# Conditions under which $\lim_{s\to1^+}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^s}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, limits, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

Dirichlet series are an important area of research in Analytic Number Theory, and their values at $s=1$ (or in general on the edge of their abscissa of convergence) are generally of special importance. I know that it is not true in general that

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}=\lim_{s\to1^+}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^s}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

since if so there would be a very simple proof of the PNT from just applying this to $a_n=\mu(n)$. My question is, under what conditions does (1) hold?

I can show that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}$ converges then (1) must hold using a very simple $\epsilon-\delta$ proof, but I can't find any broader statements. The ideal condition that I would like to show is that if the partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{a_n}{n}$ are bounded then then (1) must hold. I don't know how I would go about proving this though, and any insights on this general area would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: You wrote that you can show that if $\sum a_n/n$ converges, then $(1)$ must hold.  It is an obvious  necessary condition that $\sum a_n/n$  converges. But you asserted that $(1)$ is not true in general, which is true.  And it is not, therefore a sufficient condition  that $\sum a_n/n$ converge as you seem to have asserted.

Comment: The convergence of $\sum \frac{a_n}{n}$ is a necessary condition to even state $(1)$. And $(1)$ holds if and only if $\sum \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges. Are you maybe looking for criteria that guarantee the convergence from analytic properties of $\sum \frac{a_n}{n^s}$?